# ImportError: No module named vlfeat

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, vlfeat

I have installed VLFeat on anaconda environment successfully, but once I wanna import it, shows

```
>>> import vlfeat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named vlfeat
```

Any idea about this?

thanks

Comment: Seems that `vfleat` is not a python package, see this https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3311

Comment: @Ash thanks for commenting. what do you suggest?

Comment: have you tried `import cyvlfeat` ? It seems that what you are trying to import is just binding to `c` or `c++` code.

Comment: @Ash Thanks, I could solve it by your solution